# BigQuery, Wildcard table over non partitioning tables and field based partitioning tables is not yet supported

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a simple query with a wildcard table using standardSQL on Bigquery. Here's the code:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT dataset_id, SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions
FROM `dataset_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20150518' AND '20210406'
GROUP BY 1
```

My sharded dataset contains one table each day since 18/05/2015. So today's table will be 'dataset_20150518'.

The error is: 'Wildcard table over non partitioning tables and field based partitioning tables is not yet supported, first normal table dataset_test, first column table dataset_20150518.'

I've tried different kinds of select and aggregations but the error won't fix. I just want to query on all tables in that timeframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in the wildcard you have to have all the tables with same schema. In your case, you are also adding `dataset_test` which is not with the same schema than others (`dataset_test` is a partition table?)

You should be able to get around this limitation by deleting _test and other tables with different schema or by running this query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT dataset_id, SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions
FROM `dataset_20*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '150518' AND '210406'
GROUP BY 1
```

[Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables)